# Whether Sonarqube 5.0 version supports Oracle 12C

Tags: oracle, sonarqube

I'm configuring Oracle 12C with Sonarqube 5.0. I just want to check whether the below configurations are enough or I need to upgrade something else.

Sonar - Version 5.0
Java - Java JDK 11
DB - Oracle 12C

Comment: I doubt SonarQube 5 supports JDK 11 let alone Oracle 12c. Version 5 is very old version, may i know what is the reason?

Comment: it is my project configuration, they wants to migrate on premise servers to cloud.  they mentioned that we need to use JDK 11 or JDK 8 to run the Sonarqube 5.0.

Comment: SonarSource does not have the documentation for version 5.0 so it's hard to tell oracle 12c will work with 5.0. You are on your own. If i were you and have to use version 5.0 first i'll advice to go for the latest version if that not possible migrate it as you currently have jdk and database the versions as in current deployment.